# Depoying a certain build with gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, nexus

My CI has two main steps. Build and deploy. The result of build is that an artifact is uploaded to maven nexus. And currently manual deploy step just takes the latest artifact from nexus and deploys it.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

full:
  stage: build
  image: ubuntu
  script:
    - // Build and upload to nexus here

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - // Take latest artifact from nexus and deploy
  when: manual
```

But to me this doesn't seem to make that much sense to always deploy latest build from every pipeline. I think ideally deploy step of each pipeline should deploy the artifact that was build by the same pipelines build task. Otherwise deploy step of each pipeline will do exactly the same thing regardless when it is started.

So I have two questions.
1) How can I make my deploy step to deploy the version that was build by this run?
2) If I still want to keep the "deploy latest" functionality, then does gitlab support adding a task separate of each pipeline because as I explained this step doesn't make a lot of seance to be in pipeline? I imagine it being in a separate specific place.

Comment: Do you build and deploy docker images ?

Comment: No, result of build is a zip file that is pushed to maven nexus and deploy unpacks that zip into a server.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with maven and nexus, but assuming you can name the artifact before you push it, you can add one of the built-in environment variables that dictates which pipeline it's from.

ie:

```
...
Build:
stage: build
script:
  - ./buildAsNormal.sh > build$CI_PIPELINE_ID.extension
  - ./pushAsNormal.sh

Deploy:
stage: deploy
script:
  - ./deployAsNormal #(but specify the build$CI_PIPELINE_ID.extension file)
```

There are a lot of CI env variables you can use that are extremely useful. The full list of them is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html). The difference with $CI_PIPELINE_ID and $CI_JOB_ID is that the pipeline id is constant for all jobs in the pipeline, no matter when they execute. That means the pipeline id will be the same even if you run a manual step a week after the automated steps. The job id is specific to each job.

Comment: A good idea, but sadly maven nexus requires a very specific versioning format. So this means that the name of the built artifact is generated by maven and different each time. So somehow I need to persist this name in build phase and use it in deploy phase. Does GitLab CI allow something like this?

Comment: Looks like the answer below from Nicolas should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263495/depoying-a-certain-build-with-gitlab?noredirect=1#comment104771154_59275755), the usage of `artifacts:` can solve your problem.

You can put the version number in a file and get the file in the next stage :

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

full:   
  stage: build   
  image: ubuntu   
  script:
    - echo "1.0.0" > version
    - // Build and upload to nexus here   
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - version
    expire_in: 1 week

deploy:   
  stage: deploy   
  script:
    - VERSION = $(cat version)
    - // Take the artifact from nexus using VERSION variable and deploy   
  when: manual
```

An alternative is to build, push to nexus and use `artifact:` to pass the result of the build to the `Deploy` job :

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

full:   
  stage: build   
  image: ubuntu   
  script:
    - // Build and put the result in out/ directory 
    - // Upload the result from out/ to nexus    
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - out/
    expire_in: 1 week

deploy:   
  stage: deploy   
  script:
    - // Take the artifact from in out/ directory and deploy it   
  when: manual
```